# Lenovo laptop (Thinkbook 16p Gen 2) restarts abruptly when using it. How to fix this?

Tags: windows, lenovo-laptop, kernel, event-log

I am experiencing since months a strange behaviour with my Lenovo laptop (Thinkbook 16p Gen 2 with NVIDIA graphic card GeForce RTX 3060): it abruptly restarts while I am using it (no blue screen, simply new start).

I have Windows 11 installed.

In the events log I see a **Kernel Power 41 (63)** and looking on the internet I tried several things to solve the issue, however without success.

The issue occurs with a frequency of around 7/10 days (depending on how often I use the laptop) and it happened also when doing simple actions (like scrolling a menu in Blender).

This is what I tried until now:

- Deactivated the fast start.
- Changed the maximum processor state to 95 % as [described here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ItEiV_E22Pw).
- I run a diagnostic scan to check for hardware failures (using the [official Lenovo software](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/solutions/ht506581-lenovo-diagnostic-solutions-downloads)). --> no problems found
- I performed a [system file checker](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/using-system-file-checker-in-windows-365e0031-36b1-6031-f804-8fd86e0ef4ca) in Windows. --> some damaged files were found and corrected

Even after all this, it restarted again today.

The Lenovo warranty has already expired, since I bought the laptop refurbished (from the official Lenovo refurbished Laptops handler in Germany). I sent them back the laptop after the issued happened 2 times, they checked it and they sent it back saying they could not find any hardware issue (that they are not responsible for the software part was written at the time of purchase).

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: I suggest contacting Lenovo Support. There may possibly be some warranty for this.

Comment: Check for driver issues by reinstalling from Device Manager, and/or downloading *from Lenovo and NVIDIA* (not from a third party). Check for an OS issue by doing a reinstall of Windows 11 from ISO, keeping all files. Also look for loose connectors -- simply reseat RAM and cable connectors.

Comment: @John the warranty has already expired

Comment: Check for over-heating.

Comment: Have you already tried reinstalling Windows from scratch ?

Comment: "bought the laptop refurbished" - I can guess which was the complaint and why it was returned ..

Comment: I'd replace the SSD with another one, just to install windows and see if it solves the issue. Keep the old one, just in case. If this fails, you can go to Lenovo and claim that IT IS hardware-issue ( which, it feels like IMHO ).

Comment: Have any modifications been made to your RAM, such as adding a new module? Could you please provide the exact model of your RAM?